# How to create dynamic variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a non-profit project, which tracks information of Incoming calls and outgoing calls. I created that completely in HTML, Javascript.

To store the caller phone number I do created a namespace as follows:

```
var allCalls={
   call1={
     phonenumber:'',     
   },
   call2={
     phonenumber:'',     
   },
   call3={
     phonenumber:'',     
   }
}
```

with this architecture it only supports 3 calls at a time. How can I make it dynamic? I mean can I generate these variables dynamically?

Comment: Generate what and when? This isn't clear enough. Also, that isn't valid javascript.

Comment: like call1,call2,call3,call4............. etc. I'll take care of when

Comment: Ermm, still doesn't make much sense mate

Comment: It is already dynamic... You can add whatever you want by `allCalls.call4 = ...`

Comment: how can I do it like allCalls.call4.number ?

Comment: it's showing undefined error message when I try to assign a number to that variable

Comment: @user3191903 - `allCalls.call4 = {phonenumber: ''}`

Comment: Thanks Derek, that's what I want :)

Comment: @user3191903 - Offtopic: Although your structure works, this is usually not how one does it. Usually what I will do is by an Array: `[{...},{...},...]` To add an item, do `yourArray.push[{...}]`

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah, I just posted an answer to that effect :) I don't want you to think I ripped it off heh.

Comment: If you appreciate an answer, don't forget to "accept" the best one by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer, underneath the voting arrows. This will also award you some reputation points! If a better answer comes along later, you can switch to that one. If you haven't taken the SO tour, check it out here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

Since `call1`, `call2`, etc, is a bit redundant, it is best to store data that is associated numerically in an array rather than an object. I recommend this (the objects will be auto-numbered in the array). **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/usegEDuz/2/edit)**

```
var calls = [];

function foo(phone) {
  return { phoneNumber: phone };
}

//call comes in
var call = foo('555-555-5555');
calls.push(call);

console.log(calls[0]); //0 is the first item.

//another call comes in
var call = foo('555-123-4567');
calls.push(call);

console.log(calls[1]); //etc
```

Note that I abstracted the created of the object into a function so as to keep things uniform, maintainable, and DRY.

Comment: This is how I would do it http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/TR4Pd/ :D

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, certainly worth noting the Object-Oriented approach!!